# Repeat a given amount of strings and count in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to give my table some input and I also want it to count every four rows.
So W01 should be in the first four rows, but it should also count 1-4, then jump to W02 before repeating the operation.

Example:

- ABC-W01_1
- ABC-W01_2
- ABC-W01-3
- ABC-W01-4
- ABC-W02-1
- ABC-W02-2
- ABC-W02-3
- ABC-W02-4
- ...

Does anyone have a clever solution for this?

(I guess I could just create it in excel and import it)

Comment: How many rows do you want to generate total? If the `ABC-W` part must be fixed, you will be able to generate at most 396 rows (99 x 4), is that enough?

Answer (score 1):

If I've really got what you want, then limiting input by 100 rows you can do:

```
  select 'ABC-W' || lpad(ceil(level / 4), 2, '0') || '_' || (1+mod(level-1, 4))
    from dual
 connect by level <= 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one silly way to do this. Generate numbers from 1 to 1000; divide by ten, and represent the number in decimal format, but using dash as the "decimal point". To get the values you want, restrict which numbers are used (greater than 10, and with the last digit between 1 and 4).

Generating the numbers is done in the `connect by` process, the numbers are filtered in the `where` clause, and the exact formatting is done in the `select` clause.

```
select  'ABC-W' || 
        to_char(level/10, 'fm00d9', 'nls_numeric_characters=-,') as str
from    dual
where   level > 10 and mod(level, 10) between 1 and 4
  and   rownum <= 120  --  Limit to 120 rows; maximum 396 with this format
connect by level <= 1000
;
```

Or, even sillier (use ABC-W as currency symbol in number format):

```
select  to_char(level/10, 'fmL00d9', 
        'nls_currency=ABC-W nls_numeric_characters=-,') as str
from    dual
where   level > 10 and mod(level, 10) between 1 and 4
  and   rownum <= 120  --  Limit to 120 rows; maximum 396 with this format
connect by level <= 1000
;
```

Note that, while this solution is indeed silly, it is 100% valid - there is no abuse of any SQL feature, they are all just used in ways they weren't designed for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting your post has a typographical error and that you want the 3rd field to be preceded by a dash `-` instead of an underscore `_`.

What you want is to [generate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5176736453562766270bc396a2b23a0) some data using dual and then have the 2nd field be a function of `rownum` and the 3rd field to be different function of `rownum`.

```
select 1 + floor((id-1)/4) f2,  1 + mod(id-1,4) f3
from ( select rownum id from dual connect by level <= 396 )
```

It looks like the width for the 2nd field is intending to limit the number of rows to 396.

Answer (score 0):

You would use this, you just need to replace xx by the number of cycle you want in the inline view t1

```sql
select 'ABC-W'||lpad(t1.lvl_1, 2, '0')||'_'||t2.lvl_2
from (
  select level lvl_1 from dual connect by level <= xx
)t1, 
(
  select level lvl_2 from dual connect by level <= 4
)t2
order by 1
;
```